# Buddy class for validation not working

Tags: c#, validation, metadata, data-annotations

I have the current piece of code :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Boo.Lang;

class Program
{
    public partial class Foo
    {
        public string SomeField { get; set; }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(FooMetadata))]
    public partial class Foo
    {
    }

    public class FooMetadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Some Field is required")]
        public string SomeField { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var sample = new Foo { SomeField = null };
        var context = new ValidationContext(sample);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(sample, context, results);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            foreach (var validationResult in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("sample is valid");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It says that sample is valid although it's not the case. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

`Validator.ValidateObject` goes through all validation attributes and throws ValidationException for the first one that fails. I don't think one can get the list of all properties that failed this way.

The MSDN documentation is a bit confusing here, it says:

> The ValidateObject method evaluates each ValidationAttribute attribute
>   that is associated with the object type. If validateAllProperties is
>   set to true, the method validates the property values of the object.

`TryValidateObject` method manual continues:

> It also checks whether each property that is marked with
>   RequiredAttribute is provided.

I confirm that it always checks all the Required attributes, regardless of validateAllProperties. But if you have, for example, a Range validation attribute it will only check it when validateAllProperties is true (because this is when it validates the property value).

A bit confusing, but as you noticed, **TryValidateObject** shows all the failed properties.

Comment: But when I put the Required attribute directly above the field in my partial class it works : I have a message that says that "SomeField" is required.